# Использование SystemParameters в XAML для получения рабочей области монитора

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Мне нужно использовать `SystemParameters` в xaml. А конкретнее, ширину и высоту рабочей области активного монитора, чтобы расположить маленькое окошко в правом нижнем углу над треей. Причем это значение может изменяться, если пользователь потянул за панель задач и расширил ее.

Есть, например, свойство `MaximumWindowTrackHeight` и `MaximumWindowTrackHeightKey` типа ResourceKey, но как пользоваться последним я не знаю. Они высвечиваются в InteliScense подсказке, когда я ввожу DynamicResource, но использовать динамичные ресурсы в биндинге я не могу. Да и что мне делать с этим ResourceKey? Объясните пожалуйста, как это все использовать? Как мне привязаться к размеру рабочей области и отлавливать ее изменения (то есть чтобы при изменении размера рабочей области обновлялось свойство, которое от него зависит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью XAML ваша задача не решается, правда не столько из-за проблем с использованием ресурсов, сколько из-за ограничений класса `SystemParameters`. Мониторов может быть несколько (а в Windows 10 — и десктопов), однако в этом классе содержится информация только об основном мониторе. И не забывайте, что панель задач может быть или только на одном мониторе, или на всех, причём везде в четырёх положениях. Логику вычисления положения окна при таком количестве условий размещать в XAML неразумно, даже если это возможно.

Воспользуйтесь перечислением мониторов в [System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) и свойством `WorkingArea`, чтобы вычислить положение. Логику можно разместить в attached behavior или code-behind.

Также посмотрите в сторону [Application Desktop Toolbars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb776821.aspx). Вы получите уведомления об изменении активной области и возможность оной управлять. Ещё можно встретить рекомендации создать развёрнутое невидимое окно и подписаться на изменения размера.

Что касается `SystemParameters`, то логика использования ключей такая:

```
Foo="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.BarKey}}"
```

Свойство `Foo` при этом должно быть dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал все в обработчике события `Load`. Получал данные о текущем экране `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle);` и прописывал все необходимые параметры. Решение через `Binding` в `XAML` не нашел